# Civi CRM Wordpress Theming

Tags: wordpress, theme

After having a little demonstration at the FOSDEM i decide to test civiCRM and maybe use it in my startup. Actually i have the vanilla default installation of CIVI on a wordpress.

My actual issue is that the UI/UX is not as good as other SAAS CRM my bizdev want to use. Is there actually a repo of theme for CIVI or need i to make one by my own ?

Comment: Seems that the padding is now back even with CAU installed and can't figure out how to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing [Shoreditch](https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch) and see if you like it better. If you want to customise things further, you could fork Shoreditch and alter it to your liking.

Comment: According to the github readme `At the moment the theme is beind developed to work only in Drupal. WordPress and Joomla are not currently supporte`

Comment: I use it with WordPress. I added a stylesheet to CiviCRM Admin Utilities which detects the presence of Shoreditch and tweaks a few elements - mainly the CiviCRM menu. You can make further tweaks in your child theme's stylesheet. But of course YMMV.

Comment: What do you have to do in CiviCRM Admin Utilities to make Shoreditch work well?  I prefer shoreditch, but my biggest issue is that the menu hides behind the wordpress menu.  What in CiviCRM Admin Utilities do I have to do? @ChristianWach

Comment: @themak Ah. Thanks for the heads up - I haven't checked compatibility recently. Will have a look and fix as soon as I get a moment.

Comment: @themak CiviCRM Admin Utilities 0.3.3 should fix the menu z-index and remove the huge top padding issue when using Shoreditch.

Comment: This is amazing! thanks @ChristianWach ! Unfortunately shoreditch is not as responsive in wordpress as I would like. However - I just tried something new - Fancy Admin UI - Im in design heaven - it just works so well with shoreditch and fixes some of the responsive issues.

Comment: @themak You should document those somewhere so they can be fixed.

Comment: @ChristianWach too late - they fixed it with the release 16

Comment: @themak What did they fix? Everything? *gasps*

Comment: oh no no no. ;) but they did fix the "missing text" and a lot of alignment issues.